# Realm - list of objects in an object (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, realm

I have a Models class defined like this:

```
class BaseModel: Object {
    var data: JSON = JSON.null

    convenience init(_ data: JSON) {
        self.init()
        self.data = data
    }

    override static func ignoredProperties() -> [String] {
        return ["data"]
    }
}

class RecipeModel: BaseModel {
    dynamic var title: String {
        get { return data["fields"]["title"].stringValue }
        set { self.title = newValue }
    }

    ... more vars ...

    var ingredients: List<IngredientsModel> {
        get {
            let ingredients = List<IngredientsModel>()

            for item in data["fields"]["ingredients"] {
                ingredients.append(IngredientsModel(item.1))
            }

            return ingredients
        }
        set { self.ingredients = newValue }
    }
}

class IngredientsModel: BaseModel {
    dynamic var text: String {
        get { return data["text"].stringValue }
        set { self.text = newValue }
    }

    ... more vars ...
}
```

And I would like to use it something like this:

```
Api.shared.fetchAllEntries().call(onSuccess: {response in
        print(response.json)

        let realm = try! Realm()
        try! realm.write {
            realm.deleteAll()
        }

        for item in response.json["items"].arrayValue {
            let recipe = RecipeModel(item)
            try! realm.write {
                realm.add(recipe)
            }
        }
    }, onError: {
        print("error")
    })
```

So basically the idea is to just pass the whole JSON to the initial `RecipeModel` class, and it should parse it out and create the objects I need in the Realm database. It works quite well except for the nested list of `IngredientsModel`. They do not get added to the realm database.

[image]

[image]

What I see as a potential problem is that I call `self.init()` before I call `self.data` in the `convenience init`, but I do not see any way to work around this. Do you guys please know how I could achieve that also the `IngredientsModel` would have its contents set up properly and I would have a list of ingredients in the `RecipeModel`?

Comment: If you want yo have `List` in database it should be `let ingredients: List<IngredientsModel>` without any custom getters/setters.

Comment: @user28434 Thanks for your answer -  yes, that would probably work, but then I would not be able to set the contents of the list directly in the variable itself, but somewhere in the viewcontroller by appending objects to the RecipeModel object, which seems a bit odd to me. Is there really no way to have custom getter for a list variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current implementation doesn't work, because you are not calling the getter/setter of `ingredients` in the `init` method of `RecipeModel` and hence the `IngredientsModel` instances are never persisted in Realm.

Moreover, using a computed property as a one-to-many relationship (Realm List) is a really bad idea, especially if you are parsing the results inside the getter for this property. Every time you call the getter of `ingredients`, you create new model objects instead of just accessing the existing ones that are already stored in Realm, but you are never deleting the old ones. If you were actually saving the `IngredientsModel` instances to Realm (which you don't do at the moment as mentioned above) you would see that your database is full of duplicate entries.

Your whole approach seems really suboptimal. You shouldn't store the unparsed `data` object in your model class and use computed properties to parse it. You should parse it when initializing your models and shouldn't store the unparsed data at all. You can use the [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper#objectmapper--realm) library for creating Realm objects straight away from the JSON response.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you, I will give the `ObjectMapper` a try and see how it works out.

Comment: No worries, glad I could help.